# Sequelize migration default for column "" cannot be cast automatically to type "enum"

Tags: sql, migration, sequelize.js, psql

I am trying to write a migration to add/remove a value to an enum in my psql database as follows:

```
up : async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
    type : Sequelize.STRING
  });

  await queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TYPE IF EXISTS "enum_Messages_status"');

  await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
    type         : Sequelize.ENUM('unread', 'opened', 'expired', 'blocked', 'refused'),
    defaultValue : 'unread'
  });
},

down : async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
    type : Sequelize.STRING
  });

  await queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TYPE IF EXISTS "enum_Messages_status"');

  await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
    type         : Sequelize.ENUM('unread', 'opened', 'expired', 'blocked'),
    defaultValue : 'unread'
  });
}
```

Unfortunately the `down` method returns: `ERROR: default for column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type "enum_Messages_status"`.

If I try to change the `down` to:

```
await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
  type   : 'ENUM USING CAST("status" as ENUM)',
  values : [
    'unread',
    'opened',
    'expired',
    'blocked'
  ],
  defaultValue : 'unread'
});
```

I get another error: `ERROR: type "enum" does not exist`.

What can I do here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can't cast and define the enum at the same command. Also, your cast needs to be to your specific type.

What you can do to handle it with is to split the enum definition and column change into two commands:

```js
// Manually define the new type
await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`CREATE TYPE "enum_Messages_status" AS ENUM('unread', 'opened', 'expired', 'blocked')`);

// Use it to perform the cast
await queryInterface.changeColumn('Messages', 'status', {
  type: `"enum_Messages_status" USING CAST("status" as "enum_Messages_status")`,
});
```

For the opposite migration you'll need to reverse the order and drop the type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using sequelize db handled transactions here because if one migration fails other two passes then you will not be able to undo migrations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).